Error Fetching Data during Next.js Build: Issue with Localhost and Build Process (ECONNREFUSED)
I'm encountering an issue while building my Next.js project (version 14.1.4) with the Next.js server. The project runs smoothly with 'npm run dev', but I encounter an error during the build process. Upon researching, I discovered that the issue arises because my project is offline when building, and I'm using localhost to fetch data. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
